# how to get parent node in my html code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code :

```
<p ><script>console.log($(this).parent())</script></p>
<p ><script>console.log($(this).parent())</script></p>
<p ><script>console.log($(this).parent())</script></p>
<p ><script>console.log($(this).parent())</script></p>
```

but  this code cant get the

element , it show `[]`

so  how can i get the p element that  dont add any classname in it ,

thanks

**updated**

it is ok now , use this code :

```
$("script").last().parent()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is ok now :

```
<p class="1"><script>console.log($("script").last().parent())</script></p>
<p class="2"><script>console.log($("script").last().parent())</script></p>
<p ><script>console.log($("script").last().parent())</script></p>
<p class="4"><script>console.log($("script").last().parent())</script></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of execution `this` points to the `window` object.

What you can do is give the script tag a ID.

```
<p><script id="scr">console.log($('#scr').parent())</script></p>
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Y86fa/1/

Comment: Because i have many <p> , so i cant get the current <p> use this method .

Comment: @zjm1126 If you can please explain what you are really trying to do, i am pretty sure there is a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
$(this).parents()
```

`parent()` is used for immediate parent.